How to get the range of a when given "there exists $x>0$ such that $e^x - ax < 1$"
English version:
Consider the two statements
$p$ : "there exists $x>0$ such that $e^x - ax < 1$"
$q$ : "$f:x\mapsto - (a - 1)^x$ is decreasing"
Then which of the following is true ?
A. $p\implies q$ but $q \;\,\,\not\!\!\!\!\implies p$.
B. $q\implies p$ but $p \;\,\,\not\!\!\!\!\implies q$.
C. $p\implies q$ and $q\implies p$.
D. $p \;\,\,\not\!\!\!\!\implies q$ and $q \;\,\,\not\!\!\!\!\implies p$.
Below it my attempt:
It is easy to see that $q$ is equivalent to $\{a > 2\}$.
How to know $q$ is equivalent to $\{a > 1\}$?
My reasoning:
$ax > e^x - 1$
$a > \frac{e^x - 1}{x}$
$a > {\frac{e^x - 1}{x}}max$
Let $f(x) = \frac{e^x - 1}{x}$
then $f'(x) = \frac{e^x * x - (e ^ x - 1)}{x^2} = \frac{e ^ x (x - 1) - 1}{x ^ 2}$
From here, I do not know how to continue...
Chinese original version:
Given that
p: exist $x > 0$, $e^x - ax < 1$成立
q: $f(x) = - (a - 1)^x$ 是减函数，
则p是q的（）
A.充分不必要条件
B.必要不充分条件
C.充要条件
D.既不充分也不必要条件

Your question needs to be in English on this forum. Please translate your question, and add what you tried and some context to be sure to receive some help.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

@Kolakoski54 thanks, could you check it again? I revised it by trying my best.

@Henriksupportsthecommunity thanks for your reference, could you help check it again?

Can you explain what you mean by "subtracting function" ? Do you mean negative ?

@Kolakoski54 sorry, I may use the wrong term. It is that if $x1 < x2$, then $f(x1) > f(x2)$, we call f(x) is a subtracting function.

I suggested an edit to help you (as much as I could) with translation.

@Kolakoski54 thanks, learned from your edit!!

Solution 1:
p: there exists $$x > 0, a > \frac {e ^ x - 1}{x}$$
let $$\forall x>0\quad f(x) = \frac {e ^ x-1}x$$
and
$$f(0) =\lim_{x\to0}\frac {e ^ x - 1}{x} =\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x}{1} = 1.$$
$$p\iff a > f(x) min$$
Below is how to calculate the minimum.
$$f'(x) = \frac {xe ^ x- (e ^ x - 1)}{x^2} = \frac {xe ^ x- e ^ x + 1}{x^2} $$
Let $$g(x)= xe ^ x- e ^ x + 1$$
then $$g(0) = 0$$
and
$$g'(x) = e ^ x\cdot1 + e^x (x - 1) = xe^x> 0$$
so $g(x)$ is an increasing function.
because $$ x > 0 $$
so $$g(x) > g (0) = 0$$
then $$f'(x) > 0$$
then $f(x)$ is an increasing function.
because $x > 0$
So $$f(x) > f(0)= 1$$
$$f(x)>1 $$
$$f(x)min=1$$
so $$a > 1$$
therefore
$$p\iff a > 1$$
$$q\iff a > 2$$
so pick B as the final answer
